# Is there a work-around to handle multiple "temporal constraints" in Flink CEP?

Tags: flink-streaming, flink-cep

As stated in CEP document (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/libs/cep.html) that only one temporal constraint is allowed in a pattern sequence, I'm struggling to find out a way to handle a business case that contains 2 temporal constraints.

I need to monitor some business events and alert on the events that meet the following rules:

1. a new account is registered
2. the account gets authenticated in 5 minutes after registration
3. the account completes at least 2 transactions which transaction amount is greater than 1000.00 in next 1 hour.

And the code is something like this:

```
Pattern<Event, ?> pattern = Pattern.<Event>begin("register").where(new SimpleCondition<Event>() {
    @Override
    public boolean filter<Event value> throws Exception {
        return (value.getEventType() == EventType.REGISTER);
    }
}).followedBy("authentication").where(new SimpleCondition<Event>() {
    @Override
    public boolean filter<Event value> throws Exception {
        return (value.getEventType() == EventType.AUTHENTICATION);
    }
}).where(new IterativeCondition<Event>() {
    @Override
    public boolean filter(Event value, Context<Event> ctx) throws Exception {
        for (Event event : ctx.getEventsForPattern("register")) {
            if (value.getEventTime() - event.getEventTime() <= 1000 * 60 * 5) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}).followedBy("transaction").where(new SimpleCondition<Event>() {
    @Override
    public boolean filter<Event value> throws Exception {
        return (value.getEventType() == EventType.TRANSACTION && value.getAmount() > 1000.00);
    }
}).where(new IterativeCondition<Event>() {
    @Override
    public boolean filter(Event value, Context<Event> ctx) throws Exception {
        for (Event event : ctx.getEventsForPattern("authentication")) {
            if (value.getEventTime() - event.getEventTime() <= 1000 * 60 * 60) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}).timesOrMore(2);
```

You can see that I use 2 IterativeConditions to handle the temporal constraints. Is there a better way to make the code more concise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you can apply only one time constraint to whole pattern right now in CEP library. What you could do though is to split you pattern into 2 sub patterns. First apply pattern that will look for REGISTER -> AUTHENTICATE and generate complex event out of those  (let's name it REGISTER_AUTHENTICATED). And then use it in the subsequent pattern REGISTER_AUTHENTICATED -> 2* TRANSACTIONS.

Then you can apply two time constraints to both of those patterns.

Comment: Hi @Dawid, thank you for the reply. But will the TRANSACTION events be filtered out by the first pattern so that the rule defined in second pattern never gets hit? For example, the incoming events has following data: {"register, 00:00:00", "login, 00:02:00", "auth, 00:04:00", "trans, 00:10:00", "trans, 00:20:00", "trans, 00:25:00"...}. After the first pattern, the events stream will be {"register, 00:00:00", "auth, 00:04:00"} thus the second pattern never takes effect. Or do I have a misunderstanding?

Comment: You would need to union it with the original stream. E.g. after splitting the original stream on register&authenticate + rest. I know it is not perfect but you get a proper handling of the time constraint.

Comment: I see. It looks this is the only way to utilize **within()** method in case of multiple temporal constraints required so far (Flink 1.5.2). Thanks for the comments and I'll have a try.